# cordova-plugin-add-swift-support selects randomly swift version on swift compiler option in xcode 11.3.1

Tags: android, swift, cordova, cordova-plugins

While trying to update swift version in xcode settings through cordova-plugin-add-swift-support, sometime it is selecting the swift version and sometimes not. Looks like xcodeProject.updateBuildProperty('SWIFT_VERSION', '5.0', buildConfig.name); is not setting correctly the swift compiler version.

Ref: https://github.com/akofman/cordova-plugin-add-swift-support/blob/master/src/add-swift-support.js#L149